# LibreOffice Impress (Powerpoint) files not opening, other LibreOffice file types opening fine

Tags: libreoffice

I was using LibreOffice Impress to edit a slideshow when it suddenly closed and I now cannot open any files or access Impress at all.

All the other LibreOffice programs (Writer etc.) are working fine.

The red dot appears next to the LibreOffice icon to show a file is open, but when I click on it LibreOffice doesn't open the file, just shows a kind of error image I haven't seen before (see attached).

I tried closing and reopening Impress, opening it from Terminal instead, and restarting the computer, but nothing works.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYnZP.png)

Comment: Try hovering the little vertical line you see left above. That may be your Impress window that is resized extremely small. When your cursor changes to a rectangle, drag to increase the window.

Comment: yes, that's solved it! Great eye - thanks very much!

Comment: I was not sure, because for me, I cannot reduce further than the size of the close button. I now copied my comment in an answer - it may help other people. I have been through that before as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try hovering the little vertical line you see left above. That may be your Impress window that is resized extremely small. When your cursor changes to a rectangle, drag to increase the window.